# Case-sensitive string word replacement from dictionary in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, substitution

I have a dictionary full of key-value pairs where the key is a word I want to search for in a string and the value is what I want to replace it with. It needs to be able to preserve case as well. I'm stumbling over the logic in this circumstance.

I was thinking it would work to split the string up into a list of words, but I'm not sure if this would be the simplest way.

```
dict = {'my':'your', 'dog':'cat'}
string = 'My dog is named Jeffrey.'
```

I'd like to substitute the values in for the keys in the string, but maintain case and punctuation.

Comment: can you please add some code

Comment: Hi Jacob! Welcome to StackOverflow, your question is too broad, as it is. Please add some code, to get a better idea of what you need. Also if you have some input data and some expected output, it'll be great.

Comment: The case is standard right nothing like `dOg`?

Comment: Yes, I should only encounter normal upper, lower, and title case

Comment: `string.replace(x, y.lower() if x.lower() == x else y.title())` assuming cases are standard. Edit: Just say your post including upper cases. If that's the case then you can turn this ternary expression into a function that infers case. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the re.sub to make a substitution case insensitive. What is really difficult is to know what letter is capital because we may have words with different sizes, so I applied the rule that the first letter in the phrase has to be capital using capitalize method.

```
import re

dict = {'my':'your', 'dog':'cat'}
inputString = 'My dog is named Jeffrey.'

for key in dict.keys():
    inputString = re.sub("(?i)"+key,dict[key],inputString)
    inputString = inputString.capitalize()

print(inputString)
```